# Table doesn't show up if a cell is empty

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html table importing javascript data into the cells and a button:

```html
<tr class="row100">
<td class="column100 column1" data-column="column1">${Store1v1}</td>
<td class="column100 column2" data-column="column2">${Region1v1}</td>
<td class="column100 column3" data-column="column3">${Edition1v1}</td>
<td class="column100 column4" data-column="column4">${StockStatus1v1}</td>
<td class="column100 column5" data-column="column5">${Price1} €</td>
<td class="column100 column6" data-column="column6"><a href="${Affiliate1}" class="button">Shop Now</a></td>
</tr>
```

It's a 10 rows and 6 columns table, and I'm facing an issue, when a data is missing the table doesn't show up at all.

Is there is a way to render out the table even if a cell is empty?
(It's a top 10 best price website, but in some cases I don't have data for all the 10 rows and if any cell is empty, the table doesn't show up at all)

Comment: Is that a template literal?

Comment: What template engine fills in the variable content, e.g. `${Store1v1}`?

Comment: Also if you expect to have missing prices what do you want to display instead? You already have the euro sign hardcoded. Maybe it would be easier if on the server you make a check for missing prices and replaces with something appropriate like 'N/A' and you will solve the rendering problem too.

Comment: Basically I'm requesting the data from a rest API, so I don't have the option to modify it and if I don't have data for all the 10 rows, then the table just doesn't renders. This is my request form example: var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET', 'xxxx');
ourRequest.onload = function () {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    //Store1
    var Store1 = JSON.stringify(ourData.products[0].offers[0].store.name); -- This is why I'm trying to edit the html table somehow to show up even with empty cells. Thanks.